# How to send multiple attachments to email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have the following simple form that is ment to send multiple files to email:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="upload-file" class="upload-file" type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
```

I am using the following php code to do the actual sending:

```
if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
        $to = 'my-email@maybe-gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Files moar files';
        $message = 'Message Body';
        $headers = 'Some random email header';
        $attachments = array();
                $myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {

                   $attachments[$i] = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                }
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
            }
```

I am using wp_mail() method, because this is in a Wordpress website(it is the same as the php mail() function).
My problem is, that I receive an email with the attachments, but the name of the file is messed up, and there is no extension, so it's hard to open it. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: according to the codex, the attachments array should just be an array of filenames: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: `The filenames in the $attachments attribute have to be filesystem paths.`
If you are talking about this - I know. I am using the tmp_name to get the filesystem path, and it works, because I get the attachments and they are what I am sending. But the name of the files is the name given as a temp file e.g.:phpG0ChLP .This name is lacking an extension, so you can't open it, unless you know what it is (jpg, pdf, so on).

Comment: i think you should do a var dump.... i'm pretty sure you meant to do `$attachments[$i] = $_FILES['my_file'][$i]['tmp_name'];`

Comment: `$_FILES['my_file'][$i]['temp_name']` does not work, I don't receive the attachment. When I do `print_r($attachments)` after a successful send, I get this: `Array ( [0] => /chroot/tmp/phpYAStpI )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you upload files in PHP, they are uploaded to a temporary directory and given a random name. This is what is stored in the 'tmp_name' key for each of the files. It also explains why each file does not have an extension when sent via email, as they are simply stored as files in the temporary directory. The original file name is stored in the 'name' key.

The easiest way to deal with this issue is to rename the files to their appropriate file names and then send them, because it doesn't seem that WordPress supports a second field to provide the file name for each file.

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/'; //Or some other temporary location
$myFile = $_FILES['my_file'];
$fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['my_file']['name'][$i]);
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)) {
        //If there is a potential file attack, stop processing files.
        break;
    }
    $attachments[$i] = $uploadfile;

}
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);

//clean up your temp files after sending
foreach($attachments as $att) {
    @unlink($att);
}
```

When dealing with files it's also a good practice to validate MIME types and restrict the types of files that you support.

WordPress wp_mail: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/
PHP POST Uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for! I knew I was doing something wrong. I do know that `['name']` stores the file's real name but when I use it, it does not give me the path (unlike the temp_name, that comes with the path, I guess), so I did not receive the files. But with your method, it works great. If anyone is using it, just note the `$uploaddir` you set for the files. Make sure you have permission on your server, or you could get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

> $attachments = array();
>
> array_push($attachments, WP_CONTENT_DIR .
>   '/uploads/my-document.pdf' ); array_push($attachments,
>   WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my-file.zip' );

It's work good for me for multiple files !
Good luck